# SIP TCP Channel with SIP Sorcery

Tags: c#, tcp, sip, tcpclient

How does I set my TCP connection to KeepAlive with SipSorcery?
As I can see in my traces, the connection between my client and server sends a [FIN, ACK] packet after 30 seconds.

I need my connection to be kept alive for SUBSCRIBE on phone events.

Some code example for my TCP Channel:

```
    SIPTCPChannel channel_Tcp = new SIPTCPChannel(localEndPoint);
    Transport = new SIPTransport(SIPDNSManager.ResolveSIPService, new SIPTransactionEngine());
    Transport.AddSIPChannel(channel_Tcp);
```

Everything works fine, until my connection get closed by FIN ACK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally sending a few null bytes out on the connection will be enough to keep the connection open. Most likely it's your own router closing the TCP connection and as long as it sees some sort of traffic going out it should leave it up.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SIPTCPChannel channel_Tcp = new SIPTCPChannel(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5060));
    var Transport = new SIPTransport(SIPDNSManager.ResolveSIPService, new SIPTransactionEngine());
    Transport.AddSIPChannel(channel_Tcp);

    IPEndPoint sipServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 5060);
    Timer keepAliveTimer = new Timer(30000);

    keepAliveTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // If the TCP channel still has a connection to the SIP server socket then send a dummy keep-alive packet.
        if(channel_Tcp.IsConnectionEstablished(sipServerEndPoint))
        {
            channel_Tcp.Send(sipServerEndPoint, new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });
        }
        else
        {
            keepAliveTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
    };

    keepAliveTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work :-( When I trace the session, my client sends a [PSH, ACK] and then the server answers [ACK]. But the connection is still being closed after 30sec from the initial connection. Does the SipSorcery PruneConnections have any effect here? Maybe some kind of a timer thats being triggered??

Comment: The prune mechanism will only close a connection if there is nothing sent or received on it for 70 minutes so it's not the cause. In your trace did you see the 4 byte keep-alive packet get sent out? Try changing the time to 15s instead of 30s and see if that helps.

Comment: Changing the elapsed time doesn't have any effects, unfortunately. If i do a tcp.analysis.keep_alive in my filter on wireshark, I can't see anything.
The only packet I see when the channel_Tcp.Send() is thrown, is the client > server [PSH, ACK] Len = 4, and after that, server > client [ACK] Len = 0.

Comment: To summarize the issue, I think I located the issue to be my remote server, that has a setting which kill my connection after a timer. If I start with a REGISTER to the server, then it won't kill the TCP connection. Thanks for your input @sipwiz